# kibana.serivce keeps restarting itself and stop working

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to create an ELK stack (it is my first time, I am a student) from a vagrant file the other 2 services are running and fine, but kibana starts running and then for no apparent reason it start restarting itself and stop working. this is the log I get with `journalctl -u kibana.service`:

```
- Logs begin at Sun 2020-11-22 18:59:43 UTC, end at Sun 2020-11-22 19:11:26 UTC. --
Nov 22 19:02:48 ubuntu-bionic systemd[1]: Started Kibana.
Nov 22 19:02:54 ubuntu-bionic kibana[5207]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-11-22T19:02:54Z","tags":["info","plugins-service"],"pid":5207,"message":"Plugin \"visTypeXy\" is disabled."}
Nov 22 19:02:54 ubuntu-bionic kibana[5207]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-11-22T19:02:54Z","tags":["info","plugins-service"],"pid":5207,"message":"Plugin \"auditTrail\" is disabled."}
Nov 22 19:02:54 ubuntu-bionic kibana[5207]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-11-22T19:02:54Z","tags":["fatal","root"],"pid":5207,"message":"{ Error: [config validation of [elasticsearch].hosts]: types that failed validation:\n- [config validation of [elasticsearch].hosts.0]: expected value of type [string] but got [Array].\n- [conf$Nov 22 19:02:54 ubuntu-bionic kibana[5207]:  FATAL  Error: [config validation of [elasticsearch].hosts]: types that failed validation:
Nov 22 19:02:54 ubuntu-bionic kibana[5207]: - [config validation of [elasticsearch].hosts.0]: expected value of type [string] but got [Array].
Nov 22 19:02:54 ubuntu-bionic kibana[5207]: - [config validation of [elasticsearch].hosts.1.0]: expected URI with scheme [http|https].
Nov 22 19:02:54 ubuntu-bionic systemd[1]: kibana.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 22 19:02:54 ubuntu-bionic systemd[1]: kibana.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 22 19:02:57 ubuntu-bionic systemd[1]: kibana.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 22 19:02:57 ubuntu-bionic systemd[1]: kibana.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Nov 22 19:02:57 ubuntu-bionic systemd[1]: Stopped Kibana.
Nov 22 19:02:57 ubuntu-bionic systemd[1]: Started Kibana.
Nov 22 19:03:03 ubuntu-bionic kibana[5347]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-11-22T19:03:03Z","tags":["info","plugins-service"],"pid":5347,"message":"Plugin \"visTypeXy\" is disabled."}
Nov 22 19:03:03 ubuntu-bionic kibana[5347]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-11-22T19:03:03Z","tags":["info","plugins-service"],"pid":5347,"message":"Plugin \"auditTrail\" is disabled."}
Nov 22 19:03:03 ubuntu-bionic kibana[5347]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-11-22T19:03:03Z","tags":["fatal","root"],"pid":5347,"message":"{ Error: [config validation of [elasticsearch].hosts]: types that failed validation:\n- [config validation of [elasticsearch].hosts.0]: expected value of type [string] but got [Array].\n- [conf$Nov 22 19:03:03 ubuntu-bionic kibana[5347]:  FATAL  Error: [config validation of [elasticsearch].hosts]: types that failed validation:
Nov 22 19:03:03 ubuntu-bionic kibana[5347]: - [config validation of [elasticsearch].hosts.0]: expected value of type [string] but got [Array].
Nov 22 19:03:03 ubuntu-bionic kibana[5347]: - [config validation of [elasticsearch].hosts.1.0]: expected URI with scheme [http|https].
Nov 22 19:03:03 ubuntu-bionic systemd[1]: kibana.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 22 19:03:03 ubuntu-bionic systemd[1]: kibana.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 22 19:03:06 ubuntu-bionic systemd[1]: kibana.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 22 19:03:06 ubuntu-bionic systemd[1]: kibana.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
Nov 22 19:03:06 ubuntu-bionic systemd[1]: Stopped Kibana.
Nov 22 19:03:06 ubuntu-bionic systemd[1]: Started Kibana.
Nov 22 19:03:11 ubuntu-bionic kibana[5385]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-11-22T19:03:11Z","tags":["info","plugins-service"],"pid":5385,"message":"Plugin \"visTypeXy\" is disabled."}
Nov 22 19:03:11 ubuntu-bionic kibana[5385]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-11-22T19:03:11Z","tags":["info","plugins-service"],"pid":5385,"message":"Plugin \"auditTrail\" is disabled."}
Nov 22 19:03:11 ubuntu-bionic kibana[5385]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-11-22T19:03:11Z","tags":["fatal","root"],"pid":5385,"message":"{ Error: [config validation of [elasticsearch].hosts]: types that failed validation:\n- [config validation of [elasticsearch].hosts.0]: expected value of type [string] but got [Array].\n- [conf$Nov 22 19:03:11 ubuntu-bionic kibana[5385]:  FATAL  Error: [config validation of [elasticsearch].hosts]: types that failed validation:
Nov 22 19:03:11 ubuntu-bionic kibana[5385]: - [config validation of [elasticsearch].hosts.0]: expected value of type [string] but got [Array].
Nov 22 19:03:11 ubuntu-bionic kibana[5385]: - [config validation of [elasticsearch].hosts.1.0]: expected URI with scheme [http|https].
Nov 22 19:03:11 ubuntu-bionic systemd[1]: kibana.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 22 19:03:11 ubuntu-bionic systemd[1]: kibana.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 22 19:03:15 ubuntu-bionic systemd[1]: kibana.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 22 19:03:15 ubuntu-bionic systemd[1]: kibana.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Nov 22 19:03:15 ubuntu-bionic systemd[1]: Stopped Kibana.
Nov 22 19:03:15 ubuntu-bionic systemd[1]: Started Kibana.
Nov 22 19:03:20 ubuntu-bionic kibana[5434]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-11-22T19:03:20Z","tags":["info","plugins-service"],"pid":5434,"message":"Plugin \"visTypeXy\" is disabled."}
Nov 22 19:03:20 ubuntu-bionic kibana[5434]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-11-22T19:03:20Z","tags":["info","plugins-service"],"pid":5434,"message":"Plugin \"auditTrail\" is disabled."}
Nov 22 19:03:20 ubuntu-bionic kibana[5434]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-11-22T19:03:20Z","tags":["fatal","root"],"pid":5434,"message":"{ Error: [config validation of [elasticsearch].hosts]: types that failed validation:\n- [config validation of [elasticsearch].hosts.0]: expected value of type [string] but got [Array].\n- [conf$Nov 22 19:03:20 ubuntu-bionic kibana[5434]:  FATAL  Error: [config validation of [elasticsearch].hosts]: types that failed validation:
Nov 22 19:03:20 ubuntu-bionic kibana[5434]: - [config validation of [elasticsearch].hosts.0]: expected value of type [string] but got [Array].
Nov 22 19:03:20 ubuntu-bionic kibana[5434]: - [config validation of [elasticsearch].hosts.1.0]: expected URI with scheme [http|https].
Nov 22 19:03:20 ubuntu-bionic systemd[1]: kibana.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 22 19:03:20 ubuntu-bionic systemd[1]: kibana.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 22 19:03:23 ubuntu-bionic systemd[1]: kibana.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 22 19:03:23 ubuntu-bionic systemd[1]: kibana.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
Nov 22 19:03:23 ubuntu-bionic systemd[1]: Stopped Kibana.
Nov 22 19:03:23 ubuntu-bionic systemd[1]: kibana.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 22 19:03:23 ubuntu-bionic systemd[1]: kibana.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 22 19:03:23 ubuntu-bionic systemd[1]: Failed to start Kibana.
```

and this is the kibana.yml:

```
server.port: 5601
elasticsearch.hosts: [“http://localhost:9200”]
server.host: “localhost”
```

it says that it expected an string but it got an array, I have tried without the [] and does not work either and the documentation and anywhere I have looked for it is with the []

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: I am using this command ```echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list``` so I guess 7.10? (It is my first time using ELK)

Comment: It doesn't look like the double quotes are the right ones. It should be `"..."` and not `“...”`. Can you fix that?